# Ghandhan statement on Characteristic of Fifth power of number $(n \cdot n \cdot n \cdot n \cdot n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have identified few unique characteristics of fifth power of a number i.e. $n \cdot  n \cdot n \cdot n \cdot n$. 
Below are the 2 Characteristics.

### For any integer number N,

1. Last digit of $N$ and its last digit of fifth power $N \cdot N \cdot N \cdot N \cdot N$ are same.
2. Value of $(N\cdot N\cdot N\cdot N \cdot N) - N$ is always divisible by $30$.

Few Examples below,

- $N = 2$,

  $$(N\cdot N\cdot N\cdot N \cdot N) = 32$$

  $$\left(\frac{(N\cdot N\cdot N\cdot N \cdot N)-N}{30}\right) = 1$$
- $N = 4$

  $$(N\cdot N\cdot N\cdot N \cdot N) = 1024$$

  $$\left(\frac{(N\cdot N\cdot N\cdot N \cdot N)-N)}{30}\right) = 34$$

If this findings are not valid please defend this statement with your examples.

Comment: What is ghandhan?

Answer (score 1):

These statements are true but almost trivial to prove. Nothing significant or earth-shattering here.